# Can someone explain to me why no new bill exist to regulate financial derivatives yet?

Tags: financial-economics, financial-markets, federal-reserve

Isn't it bad economically for soft regulation on financial instruments like derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The financial bill you're describing exists. It's called the Dodd-Frank act and was enacted after the 08' crisis to further regulate securities which includes derivatives.

https://www.sec.gov/spotlight/dodd-frank/derivatives.shtml

Before the Dodd Frank Act which passed in 2010 the main source of legislation for regulating the financial industry was The Securities Exchange act of 1934 which codified the government regulation on most financial instruments and is still the primary source of financial regulation today.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securities_Exchange_Act_of_1934